# A matrix with first row and column spanning over a sub-matrix

Tags: matrices

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
   
\begin{document}

        \[
        P=\left[
        \begin{array}{cccc|cccccccccccc}
        1      & 1 & \dots    &1            & 1 & 1&  \dots       & 1 \\
        1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &   \\
        \vdots &   &        \textbf{\Huge{C}}               & &&&  \textbf{\Huge{0}}  &    \\
        1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &   \\
        \cline{2-8}
        1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &   \\
        \cdots &   &     \textbf{\Huge{0}}     &                       &   &&\textbf{\Huge{D}} \\
        1      &   &                      &                       &   &             &
        \end{array}
        \right]
        \]

\end{document}
```

I have written the following code. The problem I am facing is I want the line to appear after the first row.
Please find the picture attached of the matrix I want to have.
How do I remove the line from the first row?
Please help

[image]

I would be happy and grateful if it be done by just doing some manipulations to my given code.
I want to do it without using any packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adapting the code of the OP:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
   
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \[
    P= 
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1      & 1 & \dots                & 1 & 1                     & 1 & \dots             & 1  \\
    1      &   &                      &   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  &                       &    \\
    \vdots &   & \textbf{\Huge{C}}    &   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  &   & \textbf{\Huge{0}} &    \\
    1      &   &                      &   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  &   &                        \\
    \cline{2-8}
    1      &   &                      &   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  &   &                        \\
    \vdots &   & \textbf{\Huge{0}}    &   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  &   &\textbf{\Huge{D}}       \\
    1      &   &                      &   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  &   &
    \end{matrix} \;
    \right]
    \]
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: The display structure `\[ ... \]` automatically centers the display, so there's no need for `\begin{center} ... \end{enter}`.  Otherwise, very effective.

Comment: Yes perfect!! Thank you very much!! You are awesome Panti!!

Comment: Hi, can you give, please, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554659/how-to-change-the-vertical-position-of-an-horizontal-line-in-a-matrix/554691#554691 an answer using nicematrix package into this question? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A proposition with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
   
\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccr}[columns-width=4mm,right-margin,nullify-dots]
1       & \Cdots & &                        & 1 \\
\Vdots  & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{C} & & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{0} &   \\
\\
  & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{0} & & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{D} &   \\
1 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (4-|2) -- (4-|6) (2-|4) -- (6-|4) ;   
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: can you give any way to do it without `nicematrix`

Comment: can't it be done by just doing some manipulations to my given code, i want to do it without using complicated packages

Answer (score 1):

With `array` and some nesting:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\bigentry}[2][\huge]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1$#2$\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\ones}{\begin{matrix} 1 \\[-1ex] \vdots \\ 1 \end{matrix}}
\left[\begin{array}{ c @{} c | c @{} }
\noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}
\begin{matrix} 1 \end{matrix} &
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\begin{matrix} 1 & \dots & 1 \end{matrix}} &
\begin{matrix} 1 & \dots & 1 \end{matrix} \\
\ones & \bigentry{\mathbf{C}} & \bigentry{\mathbf{0}} \\
\cline{2-3}
\ones & \bigentry{\mathbf{0}} & \bigentry{\mathbf{D}} \\
\noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}
\end{array}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

We need a couple of tricks because of `\vdots` not being really suitable for the purpose, so some vertical space has to be added at the top and the bottom.

Avoid `\textbf` for math objects in formulas, it should be `\mathbf`.

The nested `tabular` for `\bigentry` ensures vertical centering and can accommodate a size changing command, which would otherwise be illegal in math mode.

The command `\ones` is just a local shorthand for reducing code clutter.

Comment: Okay I will keep `mathbf` in mind, thanks a lot for suggesting

Comment: But can you do it without using any package and without using `newcommand`

Comment: @Math_Freak `array` is not essential; why would you do without `amsmath`?

Comment: Since i dont understand use of `#@`,is it possible to get rid of this `\newcommand{\bigentry}[2][\huge]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1$#2$\end{tabular}}` and do it?

Comment: @Math_Freak If your aim is to use it in MathJax, please tell it so, but in this case the question would be closed as off-topic. And no, I don't know how to make it work in MathJax and don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I use `nicematrix` package to redraw the matrix, the key point is `first-row` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
p=\left[
\begin{NiceArray}{*4{C}|*3{C}}[first-row, extra-margin=2mm]
  1 & 1 & \Cdots & 1 & 1 & \Cdots & 1 \\
  1 & \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{\mathbf{C}} & & & \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{\mathbf{0}} & & \\
  \Vdots & & & & & & \\
  1 & & & & & & \\
\cline{2-7}
  1 & \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{\mathbf{0}} & & & \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{\mathbf{D}} & & \\
  \Vdots & & & & & & \\
  1 & & & & & & \\
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the dots are going through 1 in 1st row

Comment: @Math_Freak answer changed

Comment: can u please do it without `\newcommand{\Hugeeq}[1]{\text{\Huge $\mathbf{#1}$}}`, i dont understand use of `#1`

Comment: @Math_Freak it is just a format command, if you don't like it, replace the command with what you want to display.