# How to change the vertical position of a horizontal line in a matrix?

Tags: amsmath, matrices, arrays, line, vertical-spacing

I need to adjust the vertical position of a horizontal line inside a matrix.  Here's a MWE code to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        \hline
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C
    \end{array} \right]\!.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

I don't want the line to produce any gap on the crossing vertical line, and I need to keep the `\\[2ex]` vertical spacing between each element in the matrix.  So how can I move up the horizontal line, without changing the rest of the matrix?

Comment: If you are not tied to _exactly_ `2ex` of row sep, you could also modify the `\arraystretch` for that matrix, e.g. to `\def\arraystretch{1.6}`, and then removing the additional `[2ex]` to each `\\ `. Maybe there is also a possibility to set `\arraystretch` so that is is equivalent to `\\[2ex]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a trick

```
\documentclass[11p]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[.65ex]
        \hline
        \rule[0pt]{2pt}{\heightof{A}+1ex}A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C
    \end{array} \right]
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Replace `\rule[0pt]{2pt}{\heightof{A}+1ex}` by `\rule[0pt]{0pt}{\heightof{A}+1ex}`. Also the `[.65ex]` could certainly be computed in a better way by getting the interline value in the matrix when the option `\\[0ex]` is used. I do not know this value.

[image]

For an exact control, you could go with

```
\documentclass[11p]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
        R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[1ex]
        \hline
        \rule[0pt]{2pt}{\heightof{A}+1ex}%
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
        A & B & C & A & B &C
    \end{array} \right]
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the command \heightof{A}.  A is actually a matrix element with indices (a math symbol, like R_{1212}, or with the tensor package : \tensor{R}{_{1212}} for better indices placements), and it gives a compilation error.

Comment: Hmm, using $A$ appears to solve the problem in my previous comment.

Comment: I think \rule[0pt] can be replaced with just \rule because the first optional argument is raise value, no raise is equivalent to raise 0pt? // remark, this is somewhat similar to \strut

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility, with`cellspace`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{1.6ex}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{1.6ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|>{$}Sc<{$}cc}
    \multicolumn{6}{c} {}\\
    \noalign{\vspace{-3.2ex}}
    A & B & C & A & B &C \\
    A & B & C & A & B &C \\
    A & B & C & A & B &C \\
    \hline
    A & B & C & A & B &C \\
    A & B & C & A & B &C \\
    A & B & C & A & B &C \\[-0.6ex]
\end{array} \right]. 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the cell space package doing?

Comment: It ensures a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter S (or C if you load siunitx). I used the prefix for the 4th column. It is commonly used to ensure cells contents is vertically centred in  their row.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this code it is possible to create, quickly, with `nicematrix` package. Here I add my humble version using `array` enviroment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}
  & \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix} \\
\hline
  \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}&
  \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C\\
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this rudimental solution with the vertical space for the matrices `[.3cm]`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$R=\left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}
  & \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}\\[.1cm] \\[-.1cm]
\hline\\
  \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}&
  \begin{matrix}
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C\\[.3cm]
  A & B & C
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}\right).$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd like a TikZ alternative, using its `matrix` library:

[image: matrix in TikZ]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
R = 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \matrix (matrix) 
      [
        matrix of math nodes,
        row sep = 2ex,
        column sep = \columnsep,
        left delimiter = \lbrack,
        right delimiter = \rbrack
      ]
      {
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\
        A & B & C & A & B &C \\
      };
    \draw (matrix.east)  -- (matrix.west)
          (matrix.north) -- (matrix.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you need to align `=` with the middle line in your matrix, you could `yshift` the `baseline` of your `tikzpicture`:

`\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-3pt]matrix)}]`

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the classical environment `{bmatrix}` of `amsmath` but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the array accessible by the user.

Here I use these nodes with Tikz to draw the vertical rule (not broken) and the horizontal rule (with a `yshift`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
R = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
A & B & C & A & B &C \\[2ex]
A & B & C & A & B &C
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (1-|4) -- (7-|4) 
            ([yshift=4pt]4-|1) -- ([yshift=4pt]4-|7) ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Remark: You need two compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

However, in this case, it seems that the use of the keys `cell-space-limits` of `nicematrix` does the job (no need to use Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
R = \begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|ccc}[margin,cell-space-limits=6pt]
A & B & C & A & B &C \\
A & B & C & A & B &C \\
A & B & C & A & B &C \\
\hline
A & B & C & A & B &C \\
A & B & C & A & B &C \\
A & B & C & A & B &C
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the second code]